# how to copy last column range and past to the next column range in excel table (dynamically)

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new on VBA and my requirement is  to add a new column at the end of the all tables   in my workbook and copy the last used column values into my new column with format.

```
Sub LoopThroughAllTablesinWorkbook()    
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim SheetName As String

    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        SheetName = sht.Name
        For Each tbl In sht.ListObjects  
           If (tbl.Name like ("TableSL_" & Right(SheetName,2)) = True or tbl.Name Like ("Table" & SheetName) = True) Then          
               With tbl.ListColumns(tbl.ListColumns.Count).Range
                   .Copy .Offset(0, 1)
               End With       
        Next tbl
    Next sht 
End Sub
```

---

> ```
> Name  Vorname User id
> Nag     Vad     123
> Siv     VAd     456
> Reddy   Tav     769
> Ravi    Kakki   123
> ```

Results should be

> ```
> Name  Vorname User id User id2
> Nag    Vad    123     123
> Siv    VAd    456     456
> Reddy  Tav    769     769
> Ravi   Kakki  123     123
> ```

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loops through each listobject in each worksheet are correct - you need to change what you're doing to the table to copy the last column, though:

```
Sub foo()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each tbl In sht.ListObjects
            With tbl.ListColumns(tbl.ListColumns.Count).Range
                .Copy .Offset(0, 1)
            End With
        Next tbl
    Next sht
End Sub
```

### EDIT:

If you want to test the table name before copying the last column, add an `IF` ... `END IF` section:

```
Sub AddNewColumn()
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each tbl In sht.ListObjects
            If tbl.Name Like ("TableSL_" & Right(sht.Name, 2)) Or tbl.Name Like ("Table" & sht.Name) Then
                With tbl.ListColumns(tbl.ListColumns.Count).Range
                    .Copy .Offset(0, 1)
                End With
            End If
        Next tbl
    Next sht
End Sub
```

I edited your question to improve the code formatting - hopefully you can see that when you pay careful attention to the indentation, the missing `End If` statement became obvious.

Comment: Its working fine ,but when added If condtion in the loop statement (to select speicific tables) Iam getting error.
Sub AddNewColumn()

Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim SheetName As String

  For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
  SheetName = sht.Name
For Each tbl In sht.ListObjects 
       
    If (tbl.Name Like ("TableSL_" & Right(SheetName, 2)) = True Or tbl.Name Like ("Table" & SheetName) = True) Then
    
    With tbl.ListColumns(tbl.ListColumns.Count).Range
                .Copy .Offset(0, 1)
    End With               
    Next tbl
Next sht
End Sub

Comment: [Edit] your question to show the code you are trying, and the specific error. Please don't try to post code in comments.

Comment: Thanks for the edit to your question - I've updated the answer.